# SDL_PollEvent() fails to catch SDL_QUIT inside class function?

Tags: c++, windows, sdl

trying to setup my classes to programm faster with SDL2 - so far evrything worked fine.
But in the end of my last coding session my SDL_PollEvent does no longer catch SDL_QUIT.
I´m using my own SDL_Window class to handle events and other SDL relevant Vars.
In my Window class i have the function loadEvent(), its my gameloop function, and in it i call SDL_PollEvent and right after i check if it is SDL_QUIT and if so it returns a false and ends the gameloop, otherwise it returns true. SDL_PollEvent saves into a private SDL_Event varriable of my class so i can later ask for keys pressed by looking into the event of my window class.
Any keydown event works just fine, i can end my game with esc if i want to, but i never seem to catch SDL_QUIT.
There is no error, it just does not get any SDL_QUIT back.
Any ideas what could be the problem?

Code:

```
class My_SDL_Window{
private:
 SDL_Window* window;
 SDL_Surface* surface;
 SDL_Renderer* renderer;
 SDL_Event sEvent;
 My_Object_Node* allObj;
public:
 …
 bool loadEvent()
 {
  if(SDL_PollEvent( &sEvent ) != 0)
  {
   if(sEvent.type == SDL_QUIT)
   {
    destroy();
    return false ;
   }
  }
  return true;
 }
```

Comment: Is it possibly because you're only asking for 1 event every frame?

Comment: Pls explain that in more detail, i dont seem to understand.
Do i catch more events if all i do is click on the X on the window?
Do i catch mouse down and it overrides the SDL_QUIT!? o_o
If so, what could be a possible fix? I would like to keep the idea of handling my gameloop with the loadEvent() function and save the events inside my class so i dont have to type more in my main file.

Comment: I don't think that would block SDL_QUIT, *but* it's kinda broken. If the user moves the mouse a bunch, you'll be stuck waiting for all the mouse moves before you get the quit event.

Comment: Also, how do you know it doesn't work? `destroy` is not called?

Comment: Well that, and its my gameloop function, meaning if it does return false, what it would if it would catch SDL_QUIT, the loop would end and the programm would end. Also i just printed the sEvent type right after SDL_PoolEvent to be sure, and 256 (SDL_QUIT) gets never printed.

Comment: Do you have more than one window?

Comment: `if(SDL_PollEvent( &sEvent ) != 0)` - why not `while (SDL_PollEvent(&sEvent))`?

Comment: Do you have more than one window?

Comment: No i only use one window, for some reason my Object class (a class to save evrything relevant for printing obj on the window) was the problem. As soon as i deleted evry object i was able to catch the SDL_QUIT. 
But since i cant work my program without Objects, and i was not able to make a minimal working example and ppl couldn´t help me anymore without it i  rewrote the whole programm. Since that it works just fine, i´m still not sure what exactly the problem was, but its fixed, thanks for the helpfull answers. From now on i´ll always use while instead of if for my SDL_PollEvent.

Answer (score 0):

You're only checking whether there's an event once every time the program loops.

Replace:

`if(SDL_PollEvent( &sEvent ) != 0)` , which only checks whether there are any events at all, where you then only act on the first event in that list, with:

`while (SDL_PollEvent(&sEvent))` , which loops through every event in the event queue, where you then act on every single event that was performed since the last time you checked.

Comment: YEs. I have answered the same in SDL Forums, also gave a snippet to solve the issue, but seems OP don't want do that.

Comment: What do u mean i dont want to do that? I did just that but it didn´t help to solve the problem. In the end i rewrote the whole programm cause i could not get a minimal working example and after rewriting it started working again.
I posted 3 Days ago my new code snips (on SDL forum) with the while solution.
At that point i was able to catch multiple events no problem, but SDL_QUIT could still not be catched. I still dont know what exactly the problem was, but it had something to do with my Object class, becaus without any objects in my main file it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change how you handle the `SDL_PoolEvent()` instead a `if` use `while`, with this method you will catch all events on pool not only the first one.

For example:

```
bool quit = false;
SDL_Event event;
while(!quit) {
    // Process input
    while(SDL_PollEvent(&event) > 0) {
         switch(event.type) {
             case SDL_QUIT: quit = true; break;
             case SDL_KEYDOWN: 
                 switch(event.key.keysym.sym) {
                     case SDLK_UP: go_up(); break;
                     case SDLK_DOWN: go_dowm(); break;
                     // ... other keyboard handling
                 }
                 break;
         }
    }

    // Update state
    do_game_state_update();

    // Render
    do_screen_render();
}
```